# How to change default dropdown placeholder in adminjs

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm, adminjs

I created a drop down list. It works fine, but I'm having trouble translating the "Select..." and "No options" placeholders. The photos show what I mean.

There is an example of creating this drop-down list:

**Student entity:**

```
    @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  studyStatus!: string;
```

**StudyStatusEnum**

```
enum StudyStatusEnum {
studying = 'studying',
completed = 'completed studies',
academic = 'academic leave',
deducted = 'deducted',
```

}

```
export default StudyStatusEnum;
```

**admin-panel/student/translations**

```
    export default {
  [StudyStatusEnum.academic]: 'MyTranslatedText',
  [StudyStatusEnum.completed]: 'MyTranslatedText1',
  [StudyStatusEnum.deducted]: 'MyTranslatedText2',
  [StudyStatusEnum.studying]: 'MyTranslatedText3',
};
```

**admin-panel/student/utils**

```
    const getStudentStudyStatus = (): IAvailableValues[] => {
  return Object.values(StudyStatusEnum).map((value) => {
    const label = studentStudyStatusTranslation[value as StudyStatusEnum];
    
    return { label, value };
  });
};

export default getStudentStudyStatus;
```

**student.constants**

```
 const FIELDS = {
  STUDY_STATUS: 'studyStatus',
};

export default Object.freeze({
  FIELDS,

  LIST_PROPERTIES: [
    FIELDS.STUDY_STATUS,  ],
  SHOW_PROPERTIES: [],
  EDIT_PROPERTIES: [],
  FILTER_PROPERTIES: [],
});
```

**student.resource**

```
    export default () => ({
  resource: StudentEntity,
  options: {
    navigation: { icon: 'Education' },
    
    properties: {

      [StudentConstants.FIELDS.STUDY_STATUS]: {
        availableValues: studyStatus,
      },
    },

    listProperties: StudentConstants.LIST_PROPERTIES,
  },
} as ResourceWithOptions);
```

[image: No options]

[image: "Select..."]

Comment: Can you show the code for the dropdown component? It seems that you need to update your dropdown component based on  `getStudentStudyStatus` object

Comment: @FrankMendez

`import Select, { components, NoticeProps, PlaceholderProps} from "react-select";

const NoOptionsMessage = (props: NoticeProps) => {
  return (
    <components.NoOptionsMessage {...props} children="Порожньо" />
  );
};

const Placeholder = (props: PlaceholderProps) => {
  return <components.Placeholder {...props} children={"Обрати..."}/>;
};


const CustomChange = () => {
  return <Select components={{ NoOptionsMessage, Placeholder }}
    isClearable
    isSearchable
    closeMenuOnSelect={true}/>;
};

export default CustomChange;`

Comment: Here it is, but it replace the whole component and idk how to just change the placeholders